# How to build "lzma sdk" on Linux

Tags: c++, sdk, lzma

I want to use `7-zip` archive for my application and for that i download `lzma sdk`. Trying to build on Linux (Debian) but can't find how. I looking in `lzma.txt` but I can't understand how complete the job. Also I can't find any documentations or tutorials. I need detailed guide how to build `LZMA SDK` because I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](http://tukaani.org/xz/). I bet its package is already available in popular linux distros.

Of course it might be easier to use something like [libarchive](http://libarchive.github.com/) on top of that.

Comment: thanks but i want to use lzma sdk not library that depend on it.

Comment: It does provide lzma implementation "liblzma".

Comment: it is multi platform  ??
and what is license

Comment: As you can see in its webpage, it does support linux and windows and as for its license, its in the public domain.

Comment: Windows 95 and later (GCC/MinGW, GCC/MinGW-w64, GCC/Cygwin, GCC/Interix). This is problem for me becouse i want to use msvc compiler under windows

Comment: They provide prebuilt binaries, use them in whatever compiler you like.

Comment: Thanks maybe i will use libarchive. I already up vote your answer but can't mark as accepted answer because don't answer the real question "How to build “lzma sdk” on Linux", but thanks a lot,nevertheless its useful for me